# Passing struct into solidity function from brownie

Tags: solidity, brownie, abiencoderv2

Similar questions have been asked before, and I have read them but am stuck after using encode_single.  If I pass the resulting bytes into my solidity function it says "expected list or tuple, got bytes"

Here is my encoding -> 
`depositdata=encode_single('(string,address,address[],uint256[],uint256[],bytes[])',('aave','0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f',['0x6b175474e890 94c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f'],[100],[250000000000000000000],[]))`

It outputs a properly encoded bytes section.  However, when I pass it into my solidity function, even as [depositdata], I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue.  Sending structs into functions in brownie is actually very easy.

The struct is of the form

```
struct depositData { 
     string depositConnectorName;
     address vaultToken;
     address[] depositTokens;
     uint256[] depositTokenFractions;
     uint256[] newDepositAmount;
     bytes[] depositConnectorData;
}
```

And the function moveFunds(depositData[] calldata data) {} can be called like this:
`contract[0].moveFunds([['aave','0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f',['0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f'],[100],[250*10**18],[]]],{'from': accounts[0]})`

What solved my issue was not to encode the data, but to simply send it as a list of structs.  my function was requesting a list of depositData structs, so I had to add another [] around it.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you can solve it by 2 methods :

**First** :

*in solidity Code* :

```
struct YOUR_STRUCT {
uint id;
address owner }

YOUR_STRUCT[] public your_struct;
```

*in Brownie code*

```
id = youDeployedContract.your_struct(0)["id"]
owner = youDeployedContract.your_struct(0)["owner"]
```

When the 0 is your array index

**Second** :

create a view function returns the array elements;

*solidity code :*

```
function getOverview(uint index) public view returns(uint,address){
YOUR_STRUCT storage your_str = your_struct[index] ;
return (you_str.id,your_str.owner);
}
```

*Brownie code*

```
id,owner = yourDeployedContract.getOverview(0)
```